How to add value to a newly inserted column in sql using Python Mysql?
I am getting errors while inserting value to a newly added column.
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    username = 'rt',
    password = 'rt',
    database = 'demo'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO customers_1 (Address) VALUES(%s)"
val = ("Karthik")
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")


Which errors do you get?

Please add the full error log to the question.

You're missing a comma to make it a tuple: val = ("Karthik",)

are you trying to update the column for all entries?
UPDATE customers_1
SET Address = %s
WHERE condition;

w3schools
i'm aware i'm possibly misunderstanding the question asked

They still need to correct the tuple syntax.
